# Unmonitored apps for Samsung devices

Tags: android, notifications

My app has not unmonitored apps for Samsung devices which have over 7.0 SDK version.
I did not never call "force stop" for app but when app is background or killed , push notification is not coming to devices.

I have to whitelist myself in the settings what about notifications on all other Samsung devices ( over 7.0 SDK version) ? I have detected the cause of the error for you.

How can I do that programmatically like Whatsapp or WeChat?

#### Devices info

**Devices:** Samsung Note 8, Samsung A7, Samsung S6 etc
**Android version:** >= 7.0

#### Steps to reproduce

- Open Settings -> Battery
- Tap "Unmonitored Apps"

#### Screenshots

[image: screenshot_20181028-122920_device maintenance]
[image: screenshot_20181028-122945_device maintenance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot whitelist yourself programmatically.  That's the point of the whitelist.  The only people who can do that is the OEM who can include it on the phone.  They may also include some popular apps like whatsapp on the list so its preset if you download it later.  But they won't do that for some random app developer.